# Как я могу добавить перенос строк в "[{uid: 'ffa{jf45' name: 'Andrew', surname: 'Ivanov''}]"

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Предположим, у меня есть массив объектов в строковом представлении.

Я хочу добавлять перенос строки после символа **{** или **[**.

Проблема в том, что в значении свойства `uid` может содержаться символ **{** и я не хотел бы добавлять перенос именно там.

До преобразования:

```
[{uid: 'ffa{jf45', name: 'Andrew', surname: 'Ivanov'}, {uid: '122', name: 'Ann', surname: 'Smith'}]
```

После преобразования:

```
[
  { 
    uid: 'ffa{jf45' 
    name: 'Andrew', 
    surname: 'Ivanov'
  }, 
  {
    uid: '122', 
    name: 'Ann', 
    surname: 'Smith'
  }
]
```

Comment: @CreativeRusBear Добавьте в описание вопроса строковое представление ваших данных до и после необходимых преобразований.

Comment: @Leonid, добавил

Comment: Если честно я не знаю как сделать перенос строки, \n расставить? Где это потом так должно отображаться?

Comment: @Leonid, ага. Это необходимо для отображения в веб-редакторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{uid: 'ffa{jf45', name: 'Andrew', surname: 'Ivanov'}, {uid: '122', name: 'Ann', surname: 'Smith'}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))
```

Comment: то что нужно :)